# Clipping walls in Doom-style FPS view

Tags: 3d, geometry, first-person-shooter, clipping

I have two points representing a line, and a player position. I translated and rotated the points around the player, and this works just fine.

Next I want to clip the resulting line [like Bisqwit did it in his video (around 2:30-3:40)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HQYsFshbkYw), so that walls behind you won't be seen and the wall is clipped to the screen, but I don't really understand where all these constants in the code came from.

[Here is the link to his code](https://bisqwit.iki.fi/jutut/kuvat/programming_examples/portalrendering/vertrot.bas).

And here is my actual code rewritten in terrible Pascal (I just use it for testing :D )

```
program graph3dtest;
uses graph,crt, math;

// here we will set up the graphics routines
// and other stuff
procedure initgraphics;
var gd,gm: smallint;
begin
  gd:=detect; // detect the graphic size
  gm:=0;      // autodetect
  InitGraph(gd,gm,'');     // this '' is not needed for the moment...
  if GraphResult<>grok then begin
    // this is needed in case the driver won't start
    writeln(' *** ERROR *** ');
    writeln(' FATAL ERROR WHILE STARTING GRAPH UNIT... ');
    CloseGraph;
    halt;
  end;
end;

// gloabal variables here --- !
var
   vx1,vx2,vy1,vy2,px,py,angle:real;
   hwidth,hheight:real;
   tx1,tx2,ty1,ty2,tz1,tz2: real;
   running: boolean;
   kbpress: char;   // keyboard pressed
   x1,y1a,y1b,x2,y2a,y2b: integer;
   width,height: integer;
begin
  initgraphics;
  // main code here
  hwidth:=GetMaxX/2;
  hheight:=GetMaxY/2;
  circle(round(hwidth),round(hheight),10);
  writeln(hwidth,hheight);
  running:=TRUE;
  // set up variables
  vx1:=70; vy1:=20;
  vx2:=70; vy2:=70;
  px:=50; py:=50; angle:=0;
  while(running) do
  begin
    circle(round(hwidth),round(hheight),2);
    // transform the points
    tx1:=vx1 - px; tx2:=vx2 - px;
    ty1:=vy1 - py; ty2:=vy2 - py;
    // rotate them around the player
    tz1:=tx1*cos(angle) + ty1*sin(angle);
    tz2:=tx2*cos(angle) + ty2*sin(angle);
    tx1:=tx1*sin(angle) - ty1*cos(angle);
    tx2:=tx2*sin(angle) - ty2*cos(angle);
    line(round(hwidth-tx1),round(hheight-tz1),round(hwidth-tx2),round(hheight-tz2));
    // calculate the perspective projection
    x1 := round(-tx1*16/tz1); y1a:=round(-hheight/tz1); y1b:=round(hheight/tz1);
    x2 := round(-tx2*16/tz2); y2a:=round(-hheight/tz2); y2b:=round(hheight/tz2);
    width:=round(hwidth);
    height:=round(hheight);
    line(width+x1,height+y1a,width+x2,height+y2a);
    line(width+x1,height+y1b,width+x2,height+y2b);
    line(width+x1,height+y1a,width+x1,height+y1b);
    line(width+x2,height+y2a,width+x2,height+y2b);
    // get kb input
    if(keypressed) then
    begin
      kbpress:=readkey;
      if(kbpress='q') then running:=FALSE;
      if(kbpress='w') then
      begin
         ClearDevice;     // clear the screen
         px:=px+cos(angle); py:=py+sin(angle);
      end;
      if(kbpress='s') then
      begin
         ClearDevice;
         px:=px-cos(angle); py:=py-sin(angle);
      end;
      if(kbpress='a') then
      begin
         ClearDevice;
         angle:=angle-0.1;
      end;
      if(kbpress='d') then
      begin
         ClearDevice;
         angle:=angle+0.1;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

I hope you can explain it to me so that I understand it.
So the important question is the following:
Why does he use in the SUB intersect 12 variables (ok 2 are redundant because the implement ix and iy) and why do he use such numbers like 0.0001 and -20 and 5?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what specific problem you have, with what specific lines of code?

Comment: You see there the SUB intersect with 12 variables, but for what is -0.001 and 0.001 used as -20 and 5. How did he figured these out?

Comment: Try editing your question so it asks about this specifically.